# url_launcher plugin did not work in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am doing flutter apps. I want to open the website in the app. So, I have used the `url_launcher` plugin to open the URL but it did not work. There do not have to show the website in the apps.

Here is my code:

```dart
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _launch(String url) async {
    try {
      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(url);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Widget tab1() {
    return Container();
  }

  Widget tab2() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        _launch("www.google.com");
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
          labelColor: Colors.white,
          tabs: [
            new Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
            new Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
          ],
          controller: _tabController,
          indicatorColor: Colors.white,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
        ),
        bottomOpacity: 1,
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [tab1(), tab2()],
        controller: _tabController,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: no error, but also did not show the website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong package

To open any website in flutter app there is `webview_flutter` package
[Click here to check details to use this package](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have try this plugin also. But it did not very smooth

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin 
Try this package

Answer (score 1):

url_launcher works fine if used correctly

```
_launchURL() async {
    const url = "https://something.com";
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(
        url,
        forceWebView: false,
        enableJavaScript: true,
        headers: <String, String>{'my_header_key': 'my_header_value'},);
    } else {
      
      throw 'Could not launch ';
    }
  }
```

The documentation shows when and why to use forceWebView and enableJavaScript.

Note however that the Android 11 (API Level 30) will give you some issues.
canLaunch returns false in this case.
To make it work on that I had to add the following in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
           android:exported="false"/>
```

That alone did not work so I did some more digging and found this:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility#all-apps

I then added the following to my AndroidManifest.xml as well and solved it for me:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello this your all code in this file?

At first point there are missing some imports at the beginning of the file ;)

For example you need to add

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```

Did you run

```
pub get
```

after modyfiying pubspec.yaml file ?

Comment: An error would appear if he had forgotten to include the imports

Answer (score 0):

The url should have the proper Scheme:

> http: , https:, e.g. http://flutter.dev - Open URL in the default browser

https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#supported-url-schemes

```
Widget tab2() {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      _launch("https://www.google.com/");
    },
  );
}
```